# How to prevent skin resource strings from overriding languauge strings in DNN 9.2.2

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

I'm making use of resource strings in my skin. I want to be able to edit the strings via the Language section within the Site Settings. This works initially, but as soon as I install a skin update on my portal, it'll override the resources. Essentially, I want to only "apply" the resource strings in my skin if there isn't already a value added to the corresponding string in the Language settings.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a solution for this. The languages are `resx` files that are stored on the server. So you either overwrite them or you don't. You cannot configure which parts are updated and which not.

But if you choose to edit a language file at site level, DNN will create a portal specific `resx` file. Something like `MyFile.ascx.Portal-0.resx` and that won't be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks. My problem was that I included a SharedResources.resx file in the App_GlobalResources, and that the string names didn't end in ".text". Added ".text", moved the .resx to the App_LocalResources, and modified at the site level and it works fine.